# How to subtotal multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing a voting contest where people get to vote for their 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th favorite bands.  I end up with a table like this:

```
   first      second      third     fourth
   band1      band2       band3     band4
   band1      band2       band4     band3
   band4      band3       band2     band1
```

**What I would like to retrieve is a view showing the subtotal votes for each band like this:**

```
           first     second    third   fourth
  band1      2          0        0        1
  band2      0          2        1        0
  band3      0          1        1        1
  band4      1          0        1        1
```

I tried using GROUP BY with ROLLUP but I am not getting what I need.  There are a variable amount of bands.

How can I accomplish this?  TIA

UPDATE:  My data is obviously not normalized.  Let's assume there is a table with list of band names.  How then can we get the result above?

Comment: Which dbms? SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, InnoDB, ...

Comment: Show some table schemas. Sql will depend on in. For example, do you have list of bands somewhere else so you could make a join, or you have to retrieve the list from this table first?

Comment: Do you have a seperate table with the list of bands? Are you storing band IDs or band Names in your votes table?

Comment: Sorry, nubee here.  It is done in MYSQL.  There is basically one table recording all the votes.  Band names are stored in voting table.  Judging from the questions I can see this was setup wrong.  Still, is there a way to get what I need?  Thanks!

Comment: Consider normalizing your data.

Comment: Is it not possible without having a table with list of band names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the circumstances, here's a hacky way to do it (assuming a fixed `first`, `second`, `third` and `fourth` column number ([example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f30c/5/0)):

```
SELECT band,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE first = band) AS first,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE second = band) AS second,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE third = band) AS third,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE fourth = band) AS fourth
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT band
  FROM (
    SELECT first AS band FROM votes
    UNION ALL
    SELECT second AS band FROM votes
    UNION ALL
    SELECT third AS band FROM votes
    UNION ALL
    SELECT fourth AS band FROM votes
  ) x
) y
-- optionally:
ORDER BY band
```

However, I would recommend normalizing the data so the bands are in their own table:

```
-- First create a table to store the values
CREATE TABLE bands
(
  name        VARCHAR(255), -- or whatever `first`,`second`,`third`&`fourth` are
  PRIMARY KEY (name),
  UNIQUE KEY  (name)
);

-- then populate it with unique entries
INSERT INTO bands (name)
SELECT DISTINCT band
FROM (
  SELECT first AS band FROM votes
  UNION ALL
  SELECT second AS band FROM votes
  UNION ALL
  SELECT third AS band FROM votes
  UNION ALL
  SELECT fourth AS band FROM votes
) t
```

From there you could select from the bands table and bring in the counts found in the votes table.

Answer (score 0):

No normalization is always a pain. If this is just one table with all the data, something like this can be used, for each set separately:

```
select   first as "band",
         distinct count(first) as "first"
from     table
group by first
```

this will produce

```
band  first
band1 2
band2 0
band3 0
band4 1
```